# SQL Server Inner Query Problem

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a very simple query in SQL Server. But it is giving errors.

```
select * from(
 select emp_name + ' ' + emp.surname as employee from ca_contact
)
```

This query is not working.
But when I write like the below, it is working:

```
select emp_name + ' ' + emp.surname as employee from ca_contact
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need an alias. In this case `foobar`

```
select * from
   (select emp_name + ' ' + emp.surname as employee from ca_contact) foobar
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify table alias --

```
select * from(
 select emp_name + ' ' + emp.surname as employee from ca_contact
) t1
```

Comment: thank you. I am generally coding on Oracle so I could not think to put table alias.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, all derived tables must be given an alias [exception is if do not select anything from them, e.g. in an `IN/EXISTS` clause].  An alternative for what you are doing from SQL Server 2005 onwards is to use a Common Table Expression, which incidentally is also now available in recent versions of Oracle.

A simple meaningless alias

```
select * from
  (select emp_name + ' ' + surname as employee from ca_contact) [ ]
```

A Common Table Expression, also naming the column at the sametime

```
;WITH [ ](employee) AS (
    select emp_name + ' ' + surname
    from ca_contact)
select * from [ ]
```

FWIW, you can omit the CTE column names and derive them from the query

```
WITH [ ] AS (
    select emp_name + ' ' + surname as employee
    from ca_contact)
select * from [ ]
```

**Note:** Not sure how you can have `emp.surname` since there is no table/alias `emp` defined in your query

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query

```
select employee from (select emp_name + ' ' + emp.surname as employee from ca_contact) as test
```